# I want to send voice to voice chat using discord.py

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, discord.py

#### Premise · What you want to realize

I am running python source code on raspberry pi and creating a bot for discord.

I wanted to realize the function like TTSbot.
bot gets the contents of text chat and outputs sound using AquesTalkPi.

Then, I thought that I wanted raspberry pi's microphone input as bot's microphone input.

#### Problems occurring

At this stage, this program can take a text chat and play it from a raspberry pi speaker.And I confirmed that the USB microphone connected to the raspberry pie is functioning properly.
However, I did not understand exactly how to make bot connect to voice chat and make raspberry pie microphone input play bot.

I also read some programs that realize the same thing, but I could not understand it because the level was too high.

#### Corresponding source code

db_cog.py

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.voice_client import VoiceClient
import traceback
import subprocess

INITIAL_COGS = ['cog.cog']
client=discord.Client()

class Mybot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self,command_prefix):
        super().__init__(command_prefix)
        for cog in INITIAL_COGS:
            try:
                self.load_extension(cog)
            except Exception:
                traceback.print_exc()

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('login')
        print(self.user.name)
        print(self.user.id)
        print('------')
        #channel=client.get_channel("VOICE_CHANNEL_ID")
        voice = await client.join_voice_channel(client.get_channel("VOICE_CHANNEL_ID"))
        #voice=await client.connect(channel)

    async def on_message(self,message):
        if message.author.bot:
            return
        await self.process_commands(message)
        txtcmd="./AquesTalkPi '"+str(message.content)+"' | aplay"
        print(txtcmd)
        subprocess.Popen(txtcmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)


if __name__=="__main__":
    bot=Mybot(command_prefix='$')
    bot.run('MYTOKEN')
```

#### Supplemental information (FW / tool version etc.)

python 3.5.3
discord.py 1.0.0a
Raspbian Stretch with desktop November 2018